# regular expression grabbing X amount of values out in linux bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Hi guys wonder if you guys could help me I'm trying to compile a bash script that will display some values from a section of html code and I am stuck on the regular expression part,

I have the following piece of code

```
 <li><div friendid="107647498" class="friendHelperBox"><div><a href="http://www.myspace.com/rockyrobsyn" class="msProfileTextLink" title="rØbylin">rØbylin</a></div><span class="msProfileLink friendToolTipBox" friendid="107647498" style="width:90px;"><a href="http://www.myspace.com/rockyrobsyn"><img src="http://x.myspacecdn.com/modules/common/static/img/spacer.gif" source="http://c2.ac-images.myspacecdn.com/images01/59/s_8b94c89a98de643e59ab9a1cf03885c1.jpg" alt="rØbylin" class="profileimagelink" onerror="UseNoPicImage(event.target||event.srcElement)" /><span class="pilRealName">Robyn</span></a></span></div><br /><img src="http://x.myspacecdn.com/images/onlinenow.gif" /></li><li><div friendid="59261168" class="friendHelperBox"><div><a href="http://www.myspace.com/christownsendmusic" class="msProfileTextLink" title="Chris Townsend">Chris Townsend</a></div><span class="msProfileLink friendToolTipBox" friendid="59261168" style="width:90px;"><a href="http://www.myspace.com/christownsendmusic"><img src="http://x.myspacecdn.com/modules/common/static/img/spacer.gif" source="http://c4.ac-images.myspacecdn.com/images02/83/s_029c098cc40c40ff8f88fe54d53a1277.jpg" alt="Chris Townsend" class="profileimagelink" onerror="UseNoPicImage(event.target||event.srcElement)" /></a></span></div><br /><img src="http://x.myspacecdn.com/images/onlinenow.gif" /></li></ul>
```

all on one line and I would like to pull out all the text that is inside

```
..class="msProfileTextLink" title="<GRAB THIS TEXT>">....
```

I would like to grab all occurrences how am i able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that it's okay to invoke standard unix tools, not just bash built-ins

Well,

`grep -o 'class="msProfileTextLink" title="([^"])*"' file.html`

gets you as far as:

`class="msProfileTextLink" title="rØbylin"`

`class="msProfileTextLink" title="Chris Townsend"`

That assumes there's never any whitespace variation in the html - otherwise you need to do

`egrep -o 'class="msProfileTextLink"[[:space:]]*title="([^"])*"'`
inserting the `[[space]]*` whereever there might be some whitespace.

Then `grep -o '"[^"]*"$'`
Gets it down to:

"rØbylin"

"Chris Townsend"

Answer (score 1):

What about Perl? ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string = 'Your string';

$string =~ m/class=\"msProfileTextLink\" title=\"([^\"]*)\"/;

print $1; print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The following Perl-style regex should work for you:

```
m/class="msProfileTextLink"\s*title="([^"]+)"/g
```

As far as using it from a bash script, you should be able to use it in a Perl one-liner (see the **-p** and **-e** [Perl command-line options](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)), or in another language that supports perl-style regexes such as Python, PHP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk '/title="([^"]*)"/ {print substr($2,8,length($2)-8)}'
```